# Why is there a type conversion error in this code?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I don't understand why the line `this.claim = claim;` has the error "Cannot convert type 'A' to type 'Claim'". I need to return an observable because this function is called in a resolver. I don't actually need to return the claim itself, I just need to set the property on ClaimStoreService, but I couldn't figure out how to return an empty or void observable.

```
export class ClaimStoreService {

    constructor(private readonly claimService: ClaimService) { }

    claim: Claim;

    getClaim(guid: string): Observable<Claim> {
        return this.claimService.get(guid).pipe(
            take(1),
            mergeMap(claim => {
                // Cannot convert type 'A' to type 'Claim'
                this.claim = claim;
                return of(claim);
            }));
    }
}
```

Comment: I hate errors like that and I also hate using `any`. However, have you tried using `mergeMap((claim: any) =>` or `mergeMap((claim:Claim) =>` or `return this.claimService.get<Claim>(guid)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
claim: Claim;

getClaim(guid: string): Observable<Claim> {
        return this.claimService.get(guid).pipe(
            take(1),
            // give type here will solve your issue
            mergeMap((claim:Claim) => {
                this.claim = claim;
                return of(claim);
            }));
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! That didn't occur to me because I wasn't getting a type error on `return of(claim)`. I was also seeing the correct type when hovering but that may be ReSharper. I'll accept as soon as I can.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use `this.claimService.get<Claim>(guid)` you don't have to type `claim` in `mergeMap(claim =>`.